# PHP File Upload _ Internal Server Error

Tags: apache

I have a php application on apache that was working fine for 5 years until the file sizes that we are uploading began to exceed 2 gigabytes in size (some close to 2.5).  We increased these variables in the ini file and it didn't work:

memory_limit 96M
post_max_size 64M
upload_max_filesize 64M

Upon further research, i found that you all are recommending to increase the FcgidMaxRequestLen in httpd.conf file.

Quesiton is - to what value should this be increased (while keeping in mind were uploading large files)?

Thanks for any help!!

Doug

Comment: php's incredibly stupid for uploads. you need a memory_limit LARGER than post_size, as php considers uploads to be "in memory" until they actually hit disk. if you want to upload 2.5gig, you need a memory_limit of 2.5gig+extra

Comment: Thanks for the reply Marc.  Right now these are my parameters in the memory_limit = 64M;
upload_max_filesize = 4096M;
post_max_size = 4096M

Comment: Hello Marc –

The part where I'm a little hazy is that I have 2 php.ini files on the server:

_\\goxsa3380\c$\inetpub\wwwroot
• memory_limit = -1
• upload_max_filesize = 4096M
• post_max_size = 4096M 

_\\goxsa3380\c$\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.3
• memory_limit = 3500M
• upload_max_filesize = 4096M
• *there is no value for post_max here

A couple observations:
• The memory limit on the first file (from my research) is effectively set to unlimited
• I assume the memory limit on the 2nd file needs to be increased

Do I need to increase FcgidMaxRequestLen?

Thanks Marc!!!